How do I copy directory structure as symlinks inside other directory
I am looking for an easy way to backup all my dotfiles in a git repository.
Solution that I'm aiming for:

have git as my source of truth for my dotfiles contents
in my home directory backed up files would be symlinks to files in repository (so when I edit it, it's going to be edited in repository)
I can create symlinks for all files in repo with one command (directory structure would be preserved but only files should be linked

For example, I have this backup repository structure:
.config
|_ nvim
   |_ init.lua
.tmux
|_ tmux.conf
.zshrc

And I want to get this structure out of it:
home
|_ .config
|  |_ (other contents)
|  |_ nvim
|     |_ (other contents)
|     |_ link to init.lua
|_ .tmux
|  |_ (other contents)
|  |_ link to tmux.conf
|_ link to .zshrc
|_ (other home files and directories)

Other contents might exist before backup process starts, should not be backed up or affected by backup process
To my surprise I wasn't able to find an already existing solution for this. I thought that rsync does it, but googling didn't give an answer on how to do it. I tried to hack a simple bash script, but drowned in testing and amount of edge cases (i.e. for every dir ignore ., .. and .git, recurse into subdirectories and etc.)
I am sure that there should be a util for this. Maybe someone can point it out for me? Or already has a script that does this?
UPD:
Using Stéphane's idea from comments to use cp I wrote this script that fully covers my usecase:
find ./dotfiles -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | xargs realpath | xargs -i cp {} $HOME -rs --remove-destination


Would cp -rs /full/path/to/git-dir/. ~ (assuming GNU cp) work for you?

Referring to this as a “backup” seems very misleading.

Stéphane Chazelas thank you!

There is an important caveat when creating symlinks that are meant to be tracked under Git. The reference path of the source file should be relative to the repository, not absolute to the machine.
Not good for Git repositories
ln -s /Users/gio/repo/foo.md ./bar/foo.md

Good for Git repositories
cd ./bar && ln -s ../foo.md foo.md

source

this is what you want,
make a directory ie backup
mkdir backup

then cd backup
then make it a git repo git init(optional make a folder for your configs)
after that do ln -s /path/to/file/
then test it by git add .
git commit "test a symlink"
git push
then edit the file once you have done that, re git commit/push
Now, you can update the files and it will be properly updated and GitHub will nicely render it, too.
source
